# How to prevent instances from changing positions during animation?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I would like to add a wave modifer to my object that has scatterd instances. however when the wave modifer is active the instances change postion via blinking in and out. How can i prevent this?

Comment: Hi, robin. I can reproduce this. The minimal case is: with the _Wave_ modifier above the GN modifier, and no random rotation/scale, with simple instanced _Mesh Primitives_ . Maybe better to present this case, to help focus on the central problem. (If you don't mind your instances being deformed by the _Wave_, you can realize them, and put the _Wave_ below the GN. That's a fix)

Answer (score 3):

They blink in and out because the `Wave` modifier is changing the position and orientation of the surface the point distribution is happening on—as the surface moves, points get distributed all over again and they don't always fall on the same exact positions. In the setup below, I'm using two Geometry Nodes, placed before and after the Wave modifier, to work around this problem.

- First GN setup distributes points on the surface and stores them as a selection for later use, with a `Store Named Attribute`—*Boolean* node. You can name them anything, I used *dots*.
- Subsequent modifiers on an object that manipulate geometry cannot read unrealized data (like points or instances) and can only work on mesh, so I'm also converting them to vertices to make sure they move with the waves.
- In the second GN modifier, after the Wave distortion has already happened, I place my instances (in your case, leaves) on the vertices I had saved before, using a `Named Attribute`.

[image]

Comment: +1 niiiiiiiice!!